# The different of SHA512 between openssl and php

Tags: php, c, hash, sha

Here is C code:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char *hash_sha512(char *data){
    SHA512_CTX ctx;
    char *md=malloc(sizeof(char)*(SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH+1));

    SHA512_Init(&ctx);
    SHA512_Update(&ctx, data, strlen(data));
    SHA512_Final(md, &ctx);
    md[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH]='\0';

    return md;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    str=hash_sha512("GFLOuJnR19881218");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 1;
}
```

The output:

> �<�4����IIA[r�� Η#�    6π�8jD����J�b9��ږ��^X�

Here is PHP code:

```
$hash=hash('sha512', 'GFLOuJnR19881218', TRUE);
```

The output:

> �<��>4��ǰ��II�-A[r�?�� �Η#��D6π�8jD���?���J�b9��ږ��^X�

The results of C code and PHP code are different, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What error do you get? Post some examples.

Comment: Most likely `data` and `$data` are different.

Comment: Print the input and outputs of both C and PHP functions so we can see what you're talking about with `different`

Comment: The C code and PHP code are ok, but the results are different when input the same string.

Comment: go to 3rd sha implementation (i.e. http://hash.online-convert.com/sha512-generator) and check which one works wrong

Comment: The output of my C code and PHP code are garbled.

Comment: You probably want to hex encode the output first.

Comment: There is enough similarities between the strings to conclude that you are confused by encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is garbled because the output is a binary string which the browser is trying to display as ASCII or UTF-8 and can't. You need to encode both as hexidecimal, decimal, base32, or some other normal human representation and then compare them.

```
$binary = hash('sha512', 'GFLOuJnR19881218', TRUE);
$hex = hash('sha512', 'GFLOuJnR19881218');
```

> ```
> string hash ( string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
> ```
>
> *When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs lowercase hexits.*
>
> - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: The point of my question is not garblend, I want to know why the output of C and PHP is different.

Comment: @solomon_wzs, how do you know it's different? Are you running the C program from the command line and the PHP in the browser? The actual strings could be the same which is why you need to encode them so we can know for sure there is even a problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I print the output of php in shell, it is same as the output of c.